# SQL Server - Removing WHERE Clause removes result set

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, reporting

I have a strange problem with this query. When I run this as-is, I get a result set, however when I change the WHERE clause in any way or even remove it, it completely eliminates my entire result set. Any ideas as to why that could be? This is on an old, crappy vendor platform that unfortunately, I am not able to have admin access to so all I can do is run reports, and limited ones at that.

```
SELECT 
    (CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(VO.AR090_REFERENCE, 1, 1) = 'X' THEN 'CLUB' WHEN LEFT(RIGHT(VO.AR090_REFERENCE, 5), 2) = 'IP' THEN 'IP' ELSE 'CAMP' END ) AS TYPE, 
    CONVERT(NVARCHAR, VO.AR090_ISS_DATE, 101) AS SETUP, 
    VO.AR090_DESC AS FUNDER, 
    VO.AR090_REFERENCE AS VOUCH_NUM, 
    CHECKSUM(VO.AR090_REFERENCE) AS VOUCH_PARM, 
    CONVERT( NVARCHAR, VO.AR090_UPD_STAMP, 101 ) AS MODIFIED, 
    VO.AR090_AMT AS AMT, 
    VO.AR090_AMT_APPLIED AS USED, 
    VO.AR090_AMT - VO.AR090_AMT_APPLIED AS REMAIN 

FROM AR090_VOUCHER VO  
    LEFT OUTER JOIN AR020_TRANSACTIONS AR2 ON VO.AR090_ORG_CODE = AR2.AR020_ORG_CODE AND VO.AR090_REFERENCE = AR2.AR020_CC_CHECK AND AR2.AR020_TRANS_TYPE = 'VCH' 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN ER100_ACCT_ORDER AO ON AO.ER100_ORG_CODE = AR2.AR020_ORG_CODE AND AO.ER100_ORD_NBR = AR2.AR020_ORD_NBR 

WHERE 
    (VO.AR090_AMT - VO.AR090_AMT_APPLIED) > 0 

GROUP BY 
    VO.AR090_ISS_DATE,  
    VO.AR090_REFERENCE, 
    VO.AR090_AMT, 
    VO.AR090_AMT_APPLIED, 
    CONVERT( NVARCHAR, VO.AR090_UPD_STAMP, 101 ), 
    AR2.AR020_TRANS_TYPE, 
    AR2.AR020_CC_CHECK ,
    VO.AR090_DESC

ORDER BY 
    (CASE WHEN SUBSTRING( VO.AR090_REFERENCE, 1, 1 ) = 'X' THEN 'CLUB' WHEN LEFT(RIGHT(VO.AR090_REFERENCE, 5 ), 2) = 'IP' THEN 'IP' ELSE 'CAMP' END ) DESC, 
    SUBSTRING( VO.AR090_DESC, 13, LEN(VO.AR090_DESC) - 12 )
```

Comment: Why the GROUP BY? (I can't see no aggregate functions.)

Comment: Because he does want to kill duplicates ;)

Comment: I wonder if you have some nulls that the where clause inadvertently omits.

Comment: You mean OP wants `SELECT DISTINCT`?

Comment: How are you accessing the data? SSMS? Are you sure that the query is completing and returning no data as opposed to running forever/timing out/causing an unreported error?

Comment: BTW An alternate where clause would be  VO.AR090_AMT > VO.AR090_AMT_APPLIED.  This would alleviate the burden of making SQL do arithmetic prior to the comparison.

Comment: @TomH, yes, probably a reasonable number of rows to group by when the where clause is there, but a humungus number or rows without the where clause.

Comment: @TomH It turns out it was an SSMS issue. It wasn't giving me the error, but after updating, it turned out to be an issue with the substring function in the order by clause. I just removed it and it worked! Thanks for the help, it must have been a bug in my version...

Comment: @JohnPasquet, yeah I think you're right. When I updated my dbms, it started getting a substring error so I think there was a null in there somewhere. Good call!

Answer (score 0):

No. I see no situation where (properly) removing the where clause would result in LESS data. Either this is a bug (and that would be a VERY rare bug or a totally not maintained system for this to show up) or you obviously do not just delete he where clause (by logical deduction).